# What is this sad plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, roots

So a coworker gave me this. When she purchased it, it was labeled Anthurium but I don’t think that’s what it is. She said it has never bloomed and the leaves are sorta small, thin, and not quite shaped right. It’s not doing well whatever it is. So what is it and is it worth saving or should it just get tossed. [image]

Comment: Why do you think its not an Anthurium?  I'm no expert here by any stretch, but from Googling - it looks to me like it is an Anthurium which has been exposed to too much (direct) sunlight.

Comment: Also, it does not look to me like that pot has drainage holes.   Could it be suffering from not being able dry out properly between watering?  (ie water pooling at the bottom of the plant).  If so, that could cause all kinds of issues,

Comment: Anthurimum are notoriously hard to grow indoors, They need a lot of indirect light, but cool humid air, like the kind we don't provide inside in Winter. They grow on trees, so need wet then DRY each cycle. Your soil is probably mud. Move outdoors in shade as soon as frost is over, transplanted into airy orchid bark/sand/charcoal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I was just comparing it to online pics and simply thought it looks a little like one but also it’s kind of sad looking. I inherit all the sick plants at my office. Sometimes I can save them sometimes not. I’ll give your recommendations a try!